# I am trying to plot equity of profit and loss and highlight portion of equity based on some condition

Tags: python

My EquityList is a list of equity. I want to plot the equitylist and hightlight portion of this equity with red color based on the for loop. When I run the code, the code doesn't show plot.

```
chart = plt.figure()
plt.plot(range(0, len(abclist)), abclist, 'blue', linewidth=1.5)
plt.hold(True)

for p in PP:
    plt.plot(p[0], p[1], 'r', linewidth=0.2)

plt.title('abc')
plt.ylabel('a') 
plt.xlabel('b')
plt.hold(False)
plt.show(chart)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Test code everything work (in my case pyplot hold is deprecated)]
Test code everything work (in my case pyplot hold is deprecated)

Comment: I tried commending hold but still doesn't show any plot. I am not sure what is wrong.